# how i can create two dynamically components in the same component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

how i can put two components, like a button and outputText, in the same component, but in different position/time? i try to use {!v.body} (it's work) and {v.body2} but the second doesn't work. I want to do this dynamically. Can someone help me? I use lightning.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: yes, i have a component, with static component (button, outputText, inputField etc...) and in two different positions/times i want to insert dynamically two button (button1 and button2). I try to use two different {!v.body}, but i found that i can't rename {!v.body} (ex {!v.body2}) and i can't use this in my controller.js. I want use something like that:
{!v.body} (first dynamically button)
<div>
                 <ui:inputText aura:id="inputTextId" />
                </div>
{!v.body2} (second dynamically button)